# Help understanding Weyl's proof of Heisenberg's Inequality

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

https://www.math.unl.edu/~scohn1/8423/heisenberg.pdf

Can someone help me understand how they go from line to line in this proof? I'm confused by it. The proof is on the last page. Specifically how do they go from $$\left(\int \left\vert xf^*(x)f'(x)\right\vert\, dx\right)^2 \geq \frac14 \left(\int x\frac{d}{dx}\left\vert f(x)\right\vert^2\,dx\right)^2 = \frac14\left(\int \left\vert f(x)\right\vert^2 \, dx\right)^2$$ Also why were they able make the following substitution? $$\int \left\vert\widehat{f'}(k)\right\vert^2\, dk = \int\left\vert f'(x)\right\vert^2\,dk$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, note that $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}|f|^2 = ff'$.  For the second question, use the Plancherel Theorem.

Comment: So how does the x drop from the equation (from the first question)?

Comment: Integration by parts?

Comment: Wouldn't doing integral by parts give you int(xd/dxf(x)^2dx) = xf(x)^2 - int(f(x)^2dx) = xf(x)^2 - ||f(x)||^2. But you should only get the integral to be equal to ||f(x)||^2 so that once square and divided by 4 you get 1/4*||f(x)||^4.

Comment: @SamTugendhaft You're in the Schwarz class, so there shouldn't be boundary terms.  Make sure to upvote and select my answer.